# Cannot use UNION in INSERT MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, union

I have a select query that works fine. But when I wrap it into an INSERT statement, I get an error.

Error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT DISTINCT NULL AS `id`,NULL AS `core_value_id`,NULL AS `translation_id`' at line 3

I can solve this problem by using 1 insert for each source table. But is there any way to do it with a single query? Why isn't this working?

Here's the query.

```
INSERT INTO `some_table`
(
(SELECT DISTINCT
NULL AS `id`,
NULL AS `core_value_id`,
NULL AS `translation_id`,
t1.`upc` AS `source_value`,
t1.`upc` AS `value`,
COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM  `source_table_1` t1
GROUP BY `upc`)

UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT
NULL,NULL,NULL,
t1.`upc`,
t1.`upc`,
COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM  `source_table_2` t1
GROUP BY `upc`
)
ORDER BY `count` DESC
)
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `core_value_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `translation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `core_value_id` (`core_value_id`),
 KEY `translation_id` (`translation_id`),
 KEY `source_value` (`source_value`),
 KEY `value` (`value`),
 KEY `count` (`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

source_tables would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `source_table_1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `upc` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The upc columns would have data like:

```
123456789012
123456789013
123456789014
123456789015
123456789016
123456789017
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you are missing a `SELECT` clause on top of the individual selects. Furthermore the parentheses were not appropriate. Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO `some_table`
SELECT      * 
FROM 
            (
             SELECT   DISTINCT NULL AS `id`, NULL AS `core_value_id`,
                      NULL AS `translation_id`, t1.`upc` AS `source_value`,
                      t1.`upc` AS `value`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
             FROM     `source_table_1` t1
             GROUP BY `upc`

             UNION ALL

             SELECT   DISTINCT NULL, NULL, NULL, t1.`upc`, t1.`upc`, 
                      COUNT(*) AS `count`
             FROM     `source_table_2` t1
             GROUP BY `upc`
            ) AS dt
ORDER BY    `count` DESC
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, that's great! The only thing you need to add is a table alias after the closing parenthesis. I just put another "t1" there, before the `ORDER BY` and it worked. Also I realized that table aliases are unnecessary in each of the SELECTs of the UNION because each one involves only one table.

Comment: @ButtleButkus yes absolutely. I just added one for now.. I missed it.

Comment: @ButtleButkus equally unnecessary are the intermediate brackets for each union queries.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Ideally you dont require even the top level `SELECT * FROM` clause. You just can do the normal union directly. But I see that less elegant.