# INSERT in some tables's Simultaneous in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, union-all

I try to insert my data to some table's of database I have tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_18189 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '1', '4 B', '%', '0', '0')  
INSERT INTO tbl_3823 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '24000', '30 M', '34%', '885', '12.05')  
INSERT INTO tbl_67126 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '3.99 M', '10 B', '10%', '530', '14.41') 
INSERT INTO tbl_4247 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '1', '170 M', '%', '271', '22.77')  
INSERT INTO tbl_23838 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '320000', '400 M', '7%', '407', '6.91')
```

but I got

```
 Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'INSERT INTO tbl_38232 ...
```

where is the problem in my code

Comment: What is the need of `UNION ALL` if you are no doing `select` in your query?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152425/cannot-use-union-in-insert-mysql
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625532/inserting-data-into-new-table-from-union-of-two-tables
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958235/mysql-query-how-to-insert-with-union

Comment: without UNION ALL i got this Error but near UNION INSERT INTO i guess change something to fix it .

Comment: It looks that you are inserting on different-different tables, `UNION ALL` helps where you have to insert bulk data using `UNION ALL` in same table

Comment: You are inserting in different tables so union all is not needed

Comment: without UNION ALL  Error happen near UNION INSERT INTO ! what's wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure, but probably Replacing `UNION ALL` with `;`, and also add in last `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL` joins `SELECT`s and you have none in your example. Remove them.

Comment: i Remove them but i recive below error:for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tbl_38232

Comment: Please update your question. I cannot see your screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_18189 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '1', '4 B', '%', '0', '0'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_3823 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '24000', '30 M', '34%', '885', '12.05');
INSERT INTO tbl_67126 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '3.99 M', '10 B', '10%', '530', '14.41'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_4247 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '1', '170 M', '%', '271', '22.77'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_23838 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES ( '320000', '400 M', '7%', '407', '6.91');
```

Comment: i try that ... but it's not work ..error  syntax to use
 near 'INSERT INTO